# Django - POST data in latin1, decode as utf-8

Tags: python, mysql, django, utf-8, character-encoding

Using mysql (not my choice), everything is set to `utf8`, `utf8_general_ci`. In the normal case everything is `utf8` and happy.

However, if I POST sth like `É’s`, some `latin1`, and save it into the database as normal, I can't call `.decode('utf-8')` on the resulting model field:

```
>>> myinstance.myfield.decode('utf-8')
...

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc9' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I want to clean all incoming data so that it can be decoded as `utf8`.

Trying an approach like [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/UjSfCWj1s2s%5B1-25%5D) just causes the `UnicodeEncodeError` upfront.

Edit: As Daniel's answer suggests, this question comes from a misunderstanding. `latin1` is not the culprit here. `.decode('utf-8')` tries to encode to ASCII, so, it will fail for unicode like `u'팩맨'.decode('utf-8')`. It pains me to leave this question up, knowing what I know now. But, maybe it will help someone. I think, since the data is actually coming back as unicode, what we were trying to do was actually equivalent to `u'É’'.decode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django fields are always unicode. Trying to call `decode` on them means that Python will try to *encode* first, to ASCII, before trying to decode as UTF-8. That clearly isn't what you want. I expect you actually just want to do `myinstance.myfield.encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: I think this is the answer; I'm going to let it marinate for a while :D